How do I change the logging level for ibkr's ibapi?
I am trying to get more detailed logging to the console. I have done it before and seen details like
4948305328 connState: None -> 0
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:4001 w/ id:1
4948305328 connState: 0 -> 1

I can't seem to get it working now. I have even tried changing the client.py source file like this:
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # << new line

and I still can't get it to log more details.

extend the EClient  and rewrite the error method
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
from ibapi.order_cancel import OrderCancel
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
import threading
import time
from mylogger import MyLogger


class IBApi(EWrapper, EClient):
    logger = MyLogger("investing")

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.close_prices = {}  # 昨天收盘价
        self.latest_prices = {}  # 最新价格
        self.account_summary = {}  # 账户余额
        self.min_tick = None  # 最小价格变动单位
        self.orders = {}
        self.current_positions = {}  # 当前持仓

        self.prices_data_received = {}  # 数据接收标志位
        self.account_summary_received = False
        self.min_tick_data_received = False
        self.positions_received = False
        self.next_order_id = None
        self.next_order_id_ready = False

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson=None):
        self.logger.debug(f"{reqId}, {errorCode}, {errorString}")


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
